# Вложенность конструкций (рекурсия). Regexp (регулярные выражения)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, mvc

При разработке своего "легковесного" шаблонизатора, ал-я CMF MODx, столкнулся с проблемой вложенности конструкций.

То, что скармливаем (упрощённая для восприятия конструкция):

```
/* html-код */
[[SNIPPET_1
    :if
        &is=`var`
        &then=`
               /* html-код */
               [[$CHUNK_1
                :if
                    &is=`var`
                    &then=`[[SNIPPET_2
                            :filter
                                &name=`var`
                           ]]`
               ]]`
        &else=`[[$CHUNK_2:upper]]`
    :filter
        &name=`var`
]]
/* html-код */
[[~LINK_1:abs]]
```

`:if, :filter, :upper...` – *фильтры (модификаторы)*, а `&is, &name …` - *переменные фильтров*.

Переменные фильтров (`` &is=`var` ``), как можно догадаться, должны содержать всё что угодно: от простой строки до html-кода приправленного *переменными шаблона* (сниппетами, чанками и т.д.)

Проблема заключается в том, как закрыть в данном случае `[[SNIPPET_1]]`, при наличии в нём других переменных шаблона.
Стоить заметить, что `[[SNIPPET_1]]` имеет два применённых к нему фильтра: `:if` и `:filter`. Это тоже необходимо учитывать.

Было бы чудесно распарсить данную конструкцию, **как есть** (т.е. учитывать и перевод строки – удобство восприятия)

Собственно, regexp pattern, который применён в проекте:

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '/\[{2}([\$\*\@\%\~]?|\+{1,2})([\w-\.]+)\s*((?:\:[\w]+\s*(?:\s*\&[\w]*\=`(?:.[^\n]*)`)*\s*)*)\s*\]{2}/iu',
    function ($call) { },
    $subject
)
```

1. Выделяет отдельно название переменной шаблона (`SNIPPET_1, CHUNK_1, SNIPPET_2 …`), его тип (`""` - сниппет, `"$"` - чанк, `"~"` - ссылка …) и фильтры с их содержимым (`` :if&is=`var`&then=`[[$CHUNK_1]]` :filter&name=`var` ``).

   В данном случае, `[^\n]` является заглушкой, т.е. содержимое переменной фильтра пишется в одну строку без переходов на следующую, чтобы определяет конец переменной фильтра, а именно:

   ```
   &then=`[[$CHUNK_1:if&is=`var`&then=`[[SNIPPET_2:filter&name=`var`]]`]]`
   ```

   Согласитесь, не очень читабельно получается.
2. Далее парсится в массив конструкция фильтров. Определяется имя фильтра (`if, filter…`)  и переменные каждого фильтра.
   Regexp pattern:

   ```
   preg_match_all('/\:([\w]*)((?:\s*\&[\w]*\=`(?:.[^\n]*|)`\s*)*)/iu', $call[3], $found);
   ```
3. И в заключении, цикличный пробег по каждому из фильтров и выполнение функции (соответствует названию фильтра).
   Для примера приведу функцию фильтра `:if`:

   ```
   preg_match_all('/\&([\w]*)\=\`((?:.[^\&]*)?(?(?=:).*?\`\]{2}(?:.[^&]*)?|(?:.[^\&\:])?))\`/iu', $subject, $found);
   ```

**Коллизии в текущем функционале шаблонизатора:**

1. Повторюсь, содержимое переменной
   фильтра пишется в одну строку без
   переходов на следующую;
2. Ошибок не замечено, только при
   двумерной вложенности. Лечится,
   созданием дополнительного (нового)
   чанка с размещением в нём
   необходимой конструкции.

---

**Резюмируя:** Уважаемые Гуру регулярных выражений, поделитесь опытом, как закрыть конструкцию при наличии в ней вложенности аналогичных конструкций.

**UPDATE:**

[@ReinRaus](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/481/reinraus) Благодарю за ответ. Несмотря на то, что направление куда копать мне подсказал [@VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) (http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.recursive.php), Вы расписали возможные подводные камни связанные с данной конструкцией.

1. Вы правы, есть проблема, т.к. внутри значений атрибутов имеется символ `` ` ``

   Впрочем, если заменить в шаблоне такого рода одинарные кавычки на что-нибудь, что более похоже на ограничение, к примеру, `&is={{…}}`, то всё шикарно.   Вот пример:

   ```
   '/\[{2}([\$\*\@\%\~]?|\+{1,2})([\w-\.]+)((?:\s*\:[\w]+\s*(?:\s*\&[\w]*\=\s*\{{2}\s*(?:[^\{\}]++|(?R))*\}{2})*)*)(?:[^\[\]]++|(?R))*\]{2}/iu'
   ```

   Выделяется название переменной шаблона (`[[имя]]`), её тип (`[[$...]]` – чанк …), а также перечень фильтров с их содержимым. (`:if…` `:filter…`), и так для каждой переменной шаблона.

   Не получилось подобрать regexp pattern для замены одинарных кавычек `` `…` `` на `{{…}}` с учётом `\s` , потому правку шаблонов придётся производить ручками. Конечно, символ `` ` `` сморится гораздо предпочтительнее. Если у Вас есть решение, то буду рад ознакомиться.
2. Вторая проблема заключается во втором паттерне (внутри callback функции), который парсит непосредственно фильтры (для каждой переменной шаблона (сниппета, чанка) их может быть несколько).

   ```
   :if
       &is={{var}}
       &then={{
              /* html-код */
              [[$CHUNK_1
               :if
                   &is={{var}}
                   &then={{[[SNIPPET_2
                           :filter
                               &name={{var}}
                          ]]}}
              ]]}}
       &else={{[[$CHUNK_2:upper]]}}
   :filter
       &name={{var}}
   ```

   Проблема заключается в выделении отдельно взятого фильтра независимо от наличия вложенных аналогичных конструкций.

   С учётом приведённого выше паттерна, фильтры хранятся в `$call[3]`.
   Можно пойти на хитрость и все конструкции `{{…}}` с их содержимым заменить на что-то иное.

   ```
   '/\{{2}(?:[^\{\}]++|(?R))*\}{2}/iu'
   ```

   Далее благополучно распарсить c исключением `[^\:]`. Ведь конструкция фильтров приобретёт более простой вид.

   ```
   :if
     &is={{var_1}}
     &then={{var_2}}
   :filter
    &name={{var_3}}
   ```

   Есть ли возможность обойтись без замены?

Comment: @ReinRaus (кончились комментарии): а можно какой-нибудь online tool для проверки? regexpal.com судя по всему не понял, что такое `++`.

Comment: http://www.regextester.com/  
Вариант **preg**.  
Если в результате есть **matched [цифра]** то строка соответствует Вашему рекурсивному шаблону. Если не соответствует, то просто будет исходный текст.  
Результат скрин:  http://s55.radikal.ru/i149/1211/ec/68e06bb7e2d4.png

Comment: @ReinRaus: хм, вы меня озадачили :) Возьму помощь клуба на SO. Тема интересная.

Comment: @vladD, бывает :) то выражение кстати было на скорую руку на рефлексах написано :) вот его более хороший вид, покажите SO лучше это:  

    ^(a(?:(?1))*b)$

Comment: @ReinRaus: разобрался, современные регулярные выражения стали сильнее. Тем не менее, написать правильный парсер на регулярных выражениях -- очень [непростая](http://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/276994) задача. Подумайте, что, если во вложенном HTML в комментарии есть `:if`? Вашему коду придётся это учитывать.

Comment: @vladD выражения из ответа справятся с этим.   
Ограничения в ответе такие:  
Внутри кода, который внутри сниппета не должно быть открывающих/закрывающих конструкций [[ и ]], либо они должны быть экранированы.  
Но это не проблема выражений. Это проблема пишущего шаблон. Никто же не считает проблемой парсера языка необходимость экранировать кавычки в строках:  

    $text= "text \" text ";
На SO Вам верно сказали: «регулярные выражения» перестают быть по-настоящему регулярными, если использовать обратные ссылки:  

    (\w+) \1 два одинаковых слова
или рекурсию:  

    (a(?1)++) аналогично a+

Comment: @vladD можете помочь с переводом того вопроса? Не силен в английском, но думаю тому ТС можно помочь. Где-то слышал про парсер html/xml на чистых регексах. Не думаю, что это трудно, скорее это нудно: учитывать в выражении все специфики формата до строгого соответствия. Как например можно написать:  

    <td align="le\"ft" >
    <td align='le\'ft'>
    <td align=left>

Comment: @ReinRaus: хм. а дважды вложенные выражения должны быть дважды экранированы?

Comment: @vladD
> Где-то слышал про парсер html/xml на
> чистых регексах

Для PHP их множество:
[http://habrahabr.ru/post/114323/][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/114323/
Некоторые из того списка, в частности "Nokogiri", являются надстройками над нативной php-библиотекой классов DOM.
Большой минус регексных решений, это их медлительность.
Для парсинга исключительно html, по мне так лучше использовать нативное решение.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Стер старое сообщение ввиду противоречия обновления ему.
Убираем все ограничения ранее наложенные и избавляемся от необходимости замен.
Выражением `$RE0` сначала выделяете все сниппеты.
Потом определяете есть ли у сниппета фильтры, и если есть, то парсите их выражением `$RE1`.
Значения аттрибутов получаете при помощи `$RE2`

```
$RE0=<<< REGEX_SNIPPET
(?P<RegExpSnippet>\\[\\[ # открывающие скобки и именованная группа для рекурсии
    (?: # скобки для альтернативы
        (?: # что будет считаться внутренностями сниппета
            \\\\. | # экранированное что угодно
            [^\\[\\]] | # не кавычка, или 
            \\[(?!\\[) | # кавычка за которой нет другой кавычки
            \\](?!\\])
        )++ | # или все это выражение снова
        (?P>RegExpSnippet) 
    )*+ # конец альтернативы, 
\\]\\]) # закрывающие скобки сниппета, конец именованной группы 
# ACHTUNG для всех кто решил поизучать это выражение и возможно составлять их в таком же стиле:
# всегда в свободной записи делайте один лишний перевод строки в конце выражения
# не повторяйте моей ошибки и полчаса убитых на ее поиск

REGEX_SNIPPET;
$RE2=<<< REGEX_ATTR
(?: # что будет внутри аттрибута, этим куском можно выделять значение аттрибута
    \\\\. | # экранированное что-то
    [^`\\[] | # не апостроф и не скобка (чтобы не дергать постоянно рекурсию)
    $RE0 | # или вложенный сниппет
    \\[ # скобка
)++

REGEX_ATTR;
$RE1=<<< REGEX_FILTER
\\s* # пробельные символы
:\\w+ # двоеточие и лат.слово
\\s*
(?: # для нескольких аттрибутов
    &\\w+\\s*=\\s*` # амперсанд, слово, равно, апостроф
    $RE2
    `\\s* # апостроф как конец атрибута
)+

REGEX_FILTER;

preg_match_all("/$RE1/xs", $text, $arr);
```

Хочу выразить свою благодарность ТС: пока работал над его вопросом левелапнулся в своем знании регулярных выражения, и теперь гораздо лучше понимаю как поступает движок регексов в тех или иных ситуациях :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, К сожалению, существует ограничение  на кол-во символов в комментариях, потому сделаю UPDATE к своему вопросу.
Незнаком с местной системой оповещения (по мылу или как-то иначе). Надеюсь Вы откликнитесь:)

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: @ReinRaus : Обязательно проверю Ваш новый вариант решения задачи:)
Я пока остановился на замене, ибо были небольшие коллизии, а именно:

    :if
        &is={{{0}}}
        &then={{{1}}}
        &else={{{2}}}
    :filter
        &is={{{0}}}

Всё легко парсится, а потом собирается.
Кстати, нашёл решение, как `...` заменить на {{...}}

<pre><code>$patterns = array('/=\\s*\`/','/\`/');
$replacements = array('={{','}}');
preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str);
</code></pre>

Comment: @vladD комментировать больше не могу. Проведите лучше эксперимент и найдите текст, который эти выражения распарсят неверно.  
И ответ на вопрос: этим выражениям все равно. Они не меняют текст, а значит экранированный символ в исходном тексте останется экранированным и в результате.

Comment: @ReinRaus: закончились комментарии там. По поводу перевода вопроса: http://pastebin.com/THdsrPBZ Теперь по поводу "выражениям всё равно": тот, для кого произведено экранирование, должен это экранирование убирать. Как например для строки `"\""` парсер строки убирает `\`. Иначе когда произойдёт подстановка, подставленный паттерн будет неверен. Видите?

Comment: @vladD все описанные там проблемы решаемы.  
При составлении регулярного выражения практически всегда идут на уступки от точных соответствий со стандартами в зависимости от конкретной структуры текста к которому эти выражения будут применены.  
Например выражение описывающее адрес электронной почты в соответствии с RFC здесь: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html  
но для бытовых задач может хватит примерно такого: `^[-\w]+@[-\w]+\.[-\w]+$`

Comment: @ReinRaus: решаемы, без сомнений, мы ведь уже это выяснили -- речь идёт лишь о сложности решения и простоте обслуживания, расширения и поддержки. Вот вам ещё пара проблем: комментарии, [CDATA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7078850/276994) и [Entity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/702222/276994). Ещё одна тонкость: то, что покатит для бытовых задач, не прокатит для сайта, иначе возможны нарушения безопасности.

Пример: кто-то написал для своего сайта парсер, который из сообщений пользователей вычищает 99,99% скриптов. Внимание, вопрос: как скоро хакеры обнаружат XSS на этом сайте?

Comment: Скажем так:  
у меня есть нож (RegExp) и есть хлеб (текст который надо разобрать, подчиненный некой системе и структуре), зачем мне точить нож до такой остроты, чтобы я им мог разрезать орех (сферический текст в вакууме), если ореха у меня нет и не будет ?

Answer (score 4):

Резюме: рекурсивные грамматики нельзя надёжно распарсить регулярными выражениями.

Регулярные выражения, к сожалению, не дают возможности парсить рекурсивный код (то есть код со вложенными как угодно глубоко конструкциями). Выразительной силы регулярных выражений не хватает на то, чтобы выразить рекурсивную зависимость. Для вашей грамматики придётся либо писать руками recursive descent parser, либо (гораздо лучше!) выучите lex/yacc, и напишите настоящий "взрослый" парсер.

(Скучное объяснение)
Дело в том, что множество языков, которые можно распарсить регулярными выражениями -- это как раз множество [регулярных языков](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar). Ваш же язык описывается как минимум [контекстно-свободной грамматикой](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), которая не является регулярной. Соответственно она и не может обрабатываться регулярными выражениями.

---

Добавка на смежную тему: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags (почитайте верхний ответ, это просто произведение искусства!)

---

**Апдейт**

Современные языки включают модифицированную версию регулярных выражений, которая справляется с рекурсивными структурами. Тем не менее, такой парсинг при помощи регулярных выражений известен своей неадекватной сложностью.

Кроме того, я не вполне понимаю формальный синтаксис языка: может ли HTML внутри `&then` содержать, например, `` <!-- `]] --> `` или просто `[[`? (Надеюсь, что нет.)

Comment: Поправка: рекурсивные грамматики **можно** надёжно распарсить регулярными выражениями :)

Comment: @ReinRaus: вы утверждаете, что язык ТС регулярный?

Comment: Он не совсем регулярный, но если наложить незначительные ограничения, то он станет таким. Ограничение такое: внутри значений атрибутов символ:  

    `
может быть только внутри вложенного сниппета.

Comment: @ReinRaus: вот вам простая рекурсивная грамматика:

    W -> empty | a W b

Она порождает, понятно, все строки вида `aaa...abbb...b`, у которых одинаковое количество `a` и `b`. Сможете написать регулярное выражение, которое определяет, принадлежит ли слово этой грамматике?

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Буду копать в сторону использования  рекурсий в регулярных выражениях. Спасибо за ссылку, улыбнуло:) 
Обратив внимание на Ваш ответ другому пользователю со ссылкой на мой вопрос, хочу отметить, что в php существует нативная библиотека классов по работе с DOM. Боюсь, что её нет возможности  использовать для своих конструкций (не html).
Есть мнение, что ответ ниже Вашего ближе к истине – буду анализировать.

Comment: @vladD только начал изучать erlang, такие выражения мне пока не понятны. Дайте, пожалуйста, в формате python, php, java, js, basic, Perl. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @romeo: Дай бог чтобы я оказался неправ -- вам будет легче :) Кстати, если вы можете априори ограничить глубину вложенности ваших конструкций, то язык станет регулярным. Но я всё равно посоветовал бы выучить lex/yacc, оно того стоит.

Comment: @ReinRaus: давайте опишу на словах. Строка W принадлежит грамматике, если она (1) пустая, или (2) может быть представлена в виде "a" + W1 + "b", где W1 -- другое слово этой грамматики. То есть имеем: "", "a" + "" + "b" == "ab", "a" + "ab" + "b" == "aabb", "a" + "aabb" + "b" == "aaabbb" и т. д. То есть в грамматике все строки вида "aaa...abbb...b", причём количество a и b одинаково. Так вот, AFAIK не существует регулярного выражения, которое принимает только слова этой грамматики.

Comment: Проверяйте:  

    <pre>
    <?
    $text="aaaabbbb";
    
    echo preg_match("/^(a((?1)|)++b)$/", $text);
    ?>
    </pre>

Comment: @VladD Вы правы. В явном виде подобные конструкции, которые формализованы разработчиком, внутри конструкции недопустимы.
>  `]] или просто [[
Единственный выход, если требуется вывести подобную конструкции, то это менять на мнемонику. Если файл шаблона, то ручками, если "сухие" данные из БД, то заменой.

    `]] => &#96;&#93;&#93;

Comment: @VladD Конечно, можно изначально формализовать так, чтобы это не при каких условиях не встречалось в выводе (хотя, если потребуется на сайте, где используется данный движок шаблонизатора вывести справку по формализации, то "ахтунг"), но тогда отсутствует удобство для разработчика/версталщика, который составляет этот шаблон. Кстати, @ReinRaus мне предлагал заменить **[** на **&sckobka;**

Answer (score 0):

Нужен синтаксический парсер:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093228/lex-and-yacc-in-php#2093228
2. https://github.com/jakubkulhan/pacc