# Как определить вложенность элемента внутри другого элемента

Tags: preg_match, php

Нужно определить находится ли тег pre внутри тега td и если находится то нечего не делать, если нет, то сделать с ним что-то. То, что ниже - не хочет работать :(

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('#<pre.+?</pre(>)|(?:(?!<pre).[^<]*)+#s', 'pre_skip', $text);

function pre_skip($m) { echo ' start '.$m[0].' end <br>';
        if (preg_match('#<td><pre.+?</pre(>)|(?:(?!<pre).[^<]*)+<\/td>#s', $m[0])) return (isset($m[1]))? $m[0]: $m[0];
        else return (isset($m[1]))? $m[0]: nl2br($m[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Могут ли внутри pre быть другие pre?
2. pre всегда рядом с td или между ними могут быть другой текст?
   Если ответы: нет, да , то выражение такое:

`preg_replace_callback("/(?<!\<td>)<pre>.*?<\/pre>(?!\<\/td>)/is", callback, $text);`

Если ответы: нет, нет , то выражение такое:

```
$RE1="(?:\\s[^>]*)?"; ничего или атрибуты тэга
preg_replace_callback("/(<td$RE1>(?:(?!\\<\/td>).)*?)(<pre$RE1>.*?<\/pre>)/is", callback, $text);
```

В группе 1 придет все от td до pre- эту группу надо вернуть в каллбаке. 
Во второй группе тэг который надо обработать.

---

Обещанный ответ:

```
$text=<<<HEREDOC
<td>
<td></td>
<pre>
txt
<pre>
<td>
text
</td>
</pre>
</pre>
[]
</td>
<pre> all okey
</pre>
<pre></pre>
HEREDOC;

$RE0="(?:\\s[^>]*)?"; // ничего или атрибуты тэга
$RE1="(?P<PRE><pre$RE0>((?:(?!\\<pre$RE0>)(?!\\<\/pre\\s*>).)*+|(?P>PRE))+<\/pre\\s*>)";
$RE2=str_replace("PRE", "TD", str_replace("pre", "td", $RE1));
$text= preg_replace_callback("/$RE1|$RE2/is", "clb", $text);
function clb($arr){
    if ($arr["TD"]) return $arr["TD"]; // ничего не делаем. побочный результат
    return "!!!";
}
echo htmlspecialchars($text);
```

Результат:

```
<td>
<td></td>
<pre>
txt
<pre>
<td>
text
</td>
</pre>
</pre>
[]
</td>
!!!
!!!
```

Comment: @ReinRaus: ну, между ними может быть хотя бы <!-- комментарий -->

Comment: Спасибо большущее :)

Comment: У меня было подобное выражение. Попробуйте разобрать файл который весит 1 мб. Сможет ли такое выражение выполнится быстро, для большой входящей строки?

В С++ при крупных входящих данных выбрасывались исключения о выходе за пределы стека. Лучше использовать специальный парсер или написать систему синтаксического разбора.

http://hashcode.ru/questions/155822/c-boost-regex-%D0%B8-pcre-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-ran-out-of-stack-space-trying-to-match-the-regular-expression

Comment: @ReinRaus: а справится ли ваш код с таким:

* `<!-- <td> --> <pre>`
* `<!-- <td><pre> -->`
* `<div class="<td>"> <pre>`
?

Comment: @manking Лет 10 назад. XML под 100М. На питоне. SAX2. (DOM при таких объёмах на той технике -- мазохизм. Про регулярки и мысли не было)

Answer (score 2):

Только что был [другой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169265/php-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-regexp-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), похожий на ваш.

Дело в том, что правильно распарсить HTML при помощи регулярных выражений невозможно :( К сожалению, так. Поэтому возьмите лучше любой настоящий парсер HTML (я уверен, что в PHP он есть), и прикрутите его. Будет работать!

Кстати, в качестве случайного бреда: а не решается ли ваша проблема при помощи CSS?

---

Апдейт:
Оказывается, современные "регулярные выражения" стали сильнее, и на них описать парсер HTML в принципе можно. Но всё равно не нужно, потому что

- HTML жутко сложен для правильной обработки
- нет, [на самом деле](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg) жутко: ваш код скорее всего не сможет отличить закрывающий тег внутри комментария от настоящего закрывающего тега, а уж какой синтаксический хаос можно создать при помощи `ENTITY`, лучше нам с вами не знать
- есть простые [встроенные](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.dom.php) [в язык](http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) [средства](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-xpathphp/index.html), позволяющие делать то, что вам надо, проще и надёжнее.

Я бы воспользовался просто XPath. Вам нужно, судя по всему,

```
//td[count(ancestor::td)=0]
```

или

```
//td[count(parent::td)=0]
```

Выглядит проще, не правда ли?

Comment: Очень жаль. Через css это реализовать нельзя. 
В основном то конструкции вида <td><pre>(.*)</pre></td> или <pre>(.*)</pre>, поэтому как то не очень хочется ради этого подключать что-то больше чем пару регулярок и функция :( Может найдется выход?

Comment: @vladD, к сожалению Вы не правы.  
Сейчас занят, ночью напишу выражение для этой задачи

Comment: @ReinRaus: хорошо, я подожду, мне интересно.